# Keras masking zero before softmax

Tags: python, keras, softmax

Suppose that I have the following output from an LSTM layer

```
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.01843184 0.01929785 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0. ]
```

and I want to apply softmax on this output but I want to mask the 0's first.

When I used

```
mask = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(lstm_hidden)
combined = Activation('softmax')(mask)
```

It didnt work. Any ideas?

Update: The output from the LSTM hidden is `(batch_size, 50, 4000)`

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to mask 0's first`? Do you want to apply `softmax` only on the values `!=0`?

Comment: @Vlad, yes this is what I want to do.

Comment: @Vlad: I am using keras

Comment: Great, you have an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom activation to achieve it. This is equivalent to mask `0`.

```
from keras.layers import Activation,Input
import keras.backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_activation(x):
    x = K.switch(tf.is_nan(x), K.zeros_like(x), x) # prevent nan values
    x = K.switch(K.equal(K.exp(x),1),K.zeros_like(x),K.exp(x))
    return x/K.sum(x,axis=-1,keepdims=True)

lstm_hidden = Input(shape=(12,))
get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})
combined = Activation(custom_activation)(lstm_hidden)

x = np.array([[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.01843184,0.01929785,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0. ]])
with K.get_session()as sess:
    print(combined.eval(feed_dict={lstm_hidden:x}))

[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.49978352 0.50021654
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: what if my lstm_hidden is of size `(batch_size,50,4000)`? I tried it but there is an error due to the shapes compatibility in the custom_activation function

Comment: @Daisy I added it to the answer.

Comment: it didn't give the expected result. I tried to update the example with the shape i have but I couldn't.

Comment: I update the example as follows: `lstm_hidden = Input(shape=(3,4)) ... x =np.array([[1, 0, 0,1],[0,0.19, 0, 0.78],[0,0,0.01843184,0.01929785]])` and got `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3, 4) for Tensor 'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 3, 4)'`

Comment: @Daisy You can use `tf.is_nan` to prevent `nan` values. I've updated my code. In addition, `nan` value in your output are always a very bad sign.  You need to re-examine your data processing or model code.